# how to used mysql dataset in time series forecasting

Tags: python, mysql, time-series, forecasting

Pandas Time series Forecasting does only work with csv file because i want to forecast my database values for next 6 months. I did fetched the data from database in my python code that means i have data as query not in csv file.So how can i used time series forecasting method.
i am using this link for forecasting http://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2016/02/time-series-forecasting-codes-python/#comment-111179
In this link they used pd.read_csv(file)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `pd.read_csv`, use `pd.read_sql` to get a database query result as a Pandas DataFrame.

You can read all about it in the [Pandas documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#sql-queries).

Comment: great. if that works for you, please close the question.